# zsh is not Recognizing an Environmental Variable - No such File or Directory - Unix - MacOs

Tags: macos, zsh

**Expected behavior**

List the documents in a directory using an environmental variable.

**Steps to Reproduce**

```
INPUT
$ export ICLOUD_D="~/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/"
$ source ~/.zshrc
$ echo $ICLOUD_D
$ ls $ICLOUD_D
```

```
OUTPUT
$ ~/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/
$ ls: ~/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/: No such file or directory
```

**Current behavior**

Shell gives me a: **No such file or directory error.**

**Steps Performed Thus Far to Fix**

If I were to simply cut and paste the file path with the command ls then I'm able to list the files as expected.

I've also tried to put quotes around the environmental variable as well.

```
$ ls "$ICLOUD_D"
```

**System information**
- OS: MacOS v 10.15
- Shell: zsh

Answer (score 2):

Do not put quotes around the environmental variable

INPUT

```
$ export ICLOUD_D=~/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/
$ source ~/.zshrc
$ echo $ICLOUD_D
$ ls $ICLOUD_D
```

OUTPUT

```
$ ~/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/
$ afile
$ bfile
$ ...
```

Comment: Only the initial `~` has to be unquoted. The rest can be quoted to avoid the need to explicitly escape any enclosed characters with `\`.